# How to create with Laravel query in controller

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

who can help me? I was selected from sql. This is my sql. 
How to create with Laravel query in controller.

```
SELECT 
    `sp`.name_en,
    `sp`.email,
    `sp`.phone,
    `post`.`name` 
    AS 
    `position_name`
FROM 
    `staff_profiles` `sp`
INNER JOIN 
    `staff_positions` `p`
INNER JOIN 
    `positions` `post`
WHERE
    `sp`.id=`p`.`staff_id` AND `p`.`position_id`=`post`.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Query Builder to build the same query:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Or you can just run your raw query using the `DB` Facade:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries

Something like this:

```
DB::select('SELECT  sp.name_en, sp.email, sp.phone, post.name AS  position_name FROM staff_profiles sp INNER JOIN  staff_positions p INNER JOIN  positions post WHERE sp.id=p.staff_id and p.position_id=post.id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Include you model like   use  BusinessObject\User; than following query is example query.

```
$matchThese = ["job_comments.status" =>1,'job_id'=>$job_id];
        $job_com = DB::table('job_comments')
            ->select('job_comments.*','users.id as userid','users.first_name','users.last_name','users.image','users.role')
            ->where($matchThese)
            ->join('users', 'job_comments.commenter_id', '=','users.id' )
            ->get();
```